# PHP to replace table tag cellspacing=”0”

Tags: php, cellspacing

table cellspacing is coded inside html table tag

can php 5 set all table cellspacing="0" without any table tag "cellspacing" ?

Comment: You seem to answer your own question in the last paragraph.

Comment: No need to involve PHP here. Do this in CSS: `border-collapse: collapse`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP just generates stuff (usually HTML, but sometimes images or anything really). The result in this case is still just HTML.

However, you could just use the `border-spacing:0` CSS rule. This removes the spaces between cells, without actually collapsing the borders so it doesn't break your layouts.

Comment: From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html): "The cellspacing attribute on the table element is obsolete."

Comment: yes! so why validator "presentation" warnings? mistaken panic. Thanks Kolink.